# Looking for the name of a piece of software that periodically records screen for time tracking

Tags: windows, screen-capture, timestamp

I once heard about it in a podcast. It sits in the background and records your screen every 'n' seconds. Then you can review your activities at the end of the day.

I work on a lot of remove desktops through out the day and most time trackers don't appear to cope with that.

My google fu has left at the moment.

Comment: … on which operating system? Please [edit] and include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found it on [productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/how-do-i-analyze-my-daily-computer-activity/1165#1165) -  [TimeSnapper Pro](http://www.timesnapper.com/)

Comment: Nice job.  Very interesting app.  I don't think I have a use for it, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options that will take screen shots periodically (they aren't linked to time tracking software):

http://freesoft80.com/products/automatically-take-screenshots-software.html

http://www2.tbb.t-com.ne.jp/wizard/en/pure_capture/

http://www.thehelper.net/forums/showthread.php/88716-Looking-for-a-programm-that-can-take-screenshots-periodically!